# Too high level of nesting C# solved but why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So i have the next statement

```
       var list = Repositories
       .Where(d => ).ToList()
       .Join(anotherlist, l => l.element.Trim().ToLower(), r => r, (l, r) => l)
       .Select(d => d.element.Trim().ToLower())
       .ToList();
```

here i got the error Too high level of nesting for select 
I was able to solve this by replacing with contains like this but why ? The join in first linq was made in memory like the second. I can't see the difference between those two.

```
var list1 = Repositories
                .Where(d => )
                .ToList();

            var list= list1
                .Where(y => anotherlist.Contains(y.element.Trim().ToLower()))
                .Select(y => y.element.Trim().ToLower())
                .ToList();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the type of `anotherlist`?

Comment: List<string> basically list of element

Comment: your where clause is empty in the first example... what was present there?

Comment: it does not matter , you can say there where d.id==1

Comment: thats probably where the error is.. if you put the actual example there it will help in getting an answer

Comment: Ofcourse you can erase the whole `.Where(...)` call, if the problem can be reproduced without it. But if the `Where` is needed to produce the error, please include it.

Comment: What is the type of `Repositories` / how is it initialized?